# Same name of executable, different location, set priorities

Tags: windows-xp, executable

I have build an executable that has the same body (the name is tree.exe) with one that windows is provided at C:\WINDOWS\system32 (tree.com).

I have set my Environment Variables that the path where my .exe resides and normally it eould be executed run, though as the same name appears in a different location the tree.com is run instead.

The question is, is it possible to set the priorities where my tree.exe can be executed instead of tree.com. Furthermore, as after the build the tree.exe is dumped to a server other users have the same problem, they cannot just run directly, they need to locate the actual item and double click it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but i think you should have the path to your executable before the system paths in `PATH` variable. Don't forget to reopen the console after the variables have been changed.

Comment: what about a batch script which will set the variables? And offtopic: is it strictly necessary for you to have the name 'tree'? What about simple renaming?

Comment: We do have 4 letter requirement for our .exe and we are using a Tree Control :) Yeah, it could be renamed, though I am just curious of other ways to overcome the issue directly.

Comment: It couldl be a way. I think the only way is to switch the PATH if i am not mistaken.